# Why some websites use placeholder divs instead of video tags?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

Instead of directly using the video tag with the poster, I see some sites are using placeholder divs and they put a fake play icon on the div.

There is no video tag inside it. But when users click on the play icon, then they insert the video tag inside the div and video starts playing. Users don't notice what is happening. Visually there is no difference.

But I'm wondering if this something can be done for optimization. Could this affect speed in a good way?

Comment: This is all for speed purpose. Placeholders are used to the page won't jump as the video loaded. And naturally it would be faster to load a div or an image then a video. I'm pretty sure youtube does this as well. Also, too many videos loaded at the same time is heavy on speed and on memory or even cpu.

Comment: @ITgoldman thank you. But can't they just use preload="none" with a poster? wouldn't it be the same effect? Lets imagine 50 videos, no autoplay, all preload="none", and in the other case you have 50 480x270 blank divs with only play icons. Which would load faster? Is this optimization worth implementing? Btw when I mean "placeholder" div they also use background image for these. Also a play icon. So users still think its a video. But actually its empty.

Comment: By embedding code of another website, they gain all the information and statistics of your users visits. The users can thus be tracked over several sites by the major player like youtube etc.  Loading the embedded code only if the user wants to see it, helps to protect the user privacy as well.